# MSE for multivariate case

Tags: mse, multivariate-regression

This is very basic, but I want to clarify the MSE in a vector-valued setting.

Given observations

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
[x_1, y_1,z_1] \\ \vdots \\ [x_n, y_n,z_n]
\end{bmatrix} $$

And estimations

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
[\hat{x_1}, \hat{y_1},\hat{z_1}] \\ \vdots \\ [\hat{x_n}, \hat{y_n},\hat{z_n}]
\end{bmatrix} $$

The MSE should be calculated as $$\frac{1}{3n} \sum_{i=1}^n ([x_i, y_i,z_i]-[\hat{x_i}, \hat{y_i},\hat{z_i}])^T([x_i, y_i,z_i]-[\hat{x_i}, \hat{y_i},\hat{z_i}])? $$

Comment: Sure--if that's meaningful for you.  Your formula is equivalent to viewing your data as a $3n$-vector $(\mathbf x^\prime ,\mathbf y^\prime, \mathbf z^\prime)^\prime$ and you are computing its MSE.  Thus, you make no distinction among the three variables.

Comment: @whuber as opposed to doing so component-wise?